# How to normalize pandas multiindex dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a questions on normalizing the counts in a grouped dataframe.

My data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'system': 'S1', 'id': '1', 'output': ['apple', 'pear']},
    {'system': 'S1', 'id': '2', 'output': []},
    {'system': 'S1', 'id': '3', 'output': []},
    {'system': 'S2', 'id': '4', 'output': ['apple', 'grape']},
    {'system': 'S2', 'id': '5', 'output': ['apple']}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which looks like this in table format:

```
  system id          output
0     S1  1   [apple, pear]
1     S1  2              []
2     S1  3              []
3     S2  4  [apple, grape]
4     S2  5         [apple]
```

How can I get normalized counts per output per system?

It should look like this:

```
system  output  perc
S1      apple   0.33
S1      pear    0.33
S2      apple   1.0
S2      grape   0.5
```

Meaning that `apple` and `pear` appear in a third of all `S1` outputs, `apple` appears in all `S2` outputs, `grape` appears in half of the `S2` outputs.

I tried to explode the outputs per system and get separate counts of IDs per system, but merging them loses the `output` column:

```
outputs = df.explode('output').groupby(['system', 'output']).count()                                                                                                                                        
counts = df.groupby('system').agg('count').id
pd.merge(outputs, counts, on="system")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pandas 0.25+, we can use `explode`:

```
(df.explode('output')
   .groupby('system')
   .apply(lambda x:x['output'].value_counts()/x['id'].nunique())
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  system level_1    output
0     S1    pear  0.333333
1     S1   apple  0.333333
2     S2   apple  1.000000
3     S2   grape  0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`Serives.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
new_df = (df.explode('output').groupby('system')['output'].value_counts()
           .reset_index(name='perc')
           .assign(perc=lambda x: x['perc'].div(x['system']\
                                                .map(df['system'].value_counts()))))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  system output      perc
0     S1  apple  0.333333
1     S1   pear  0.333333
2     S2  apple  1.000000
3     S2  grape  0.500000
```

---

**times for the sample dataframe**

```
%%timeit

new_df = (df.explode('output').groupby('system')['output'].value_counts()
           .reset_index(name='perc')
           .assign(perc=lambda x: x['perc'].div(x['system']\
                                                .map(df['system'].value_counts()))))


9.19 ms ± 64.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
(df.explode('output')
   .groupby('system')
   .apply(lambda x:x['output'].value_counts()/x['id'].nunique())
   .reset_index()
)
12.3 ms ± 134 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```